# An application of Fubini's theorem I don't understand

Tags: measure-theory, haar-measure, product-measure

Here is a result asserting that, under some technical conditions, we can replace a Borel almost everywhere homomorphism by a Borel homomorphism.
It is taken from Zimmer's book "Ergodic Theory and Semisimple Lie Groups" (pp.197, Appendix B), but I'm **not** interested in the result itself.

The main point is that **I want to understand how** its proof uses **Fubini's theorem** (click [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) for the statement), because I havent't got it.

**Basic definitions:**
By Borel structure we mean the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the topology.
For Haar measure, click [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure).

**Proposition**
Suppose $J\subseteq [0,1]$ is a topological group whose Borel structure is countably generated (i.e. there exists a countable family of Borel sets which separates points and generates the $\sigma$-algebra).
Let $G$ be a locally compact group with probability Haar measure $m$.
Let $\pi\colon G\to J$ be a Borel function s.t. $\pi(xy)=\pi(x)\pi(y)$ for almost all $(x,y)\in G\times G$.
Then there is a Borel homomorphism $\pi_0\colon G\to J$ s.t. $\pi=\pi_0$ almost everywhere (a.e.).

The **proof** starts as follows:
Consider the set 
$$H\{y\in G\mid \text{the function } x\mapsto \pi(x)^{-1}\pi(xy) \text{ is constant a.e.}\}.$$

By Fubini, $H$ is conull (i.e. the complement has measure $0$) **[and I don't understand why]**.

Later on, he uses Fubini's theorem once again, this time to prove that $\pi_0$ is Borel **[How?]**: he argues that it follows from the fact that $\pi_0(y)=\int \pi(x)^{-1}\pi(xy)\,dm$.

**Question:** As I stated above, what I look for is a clear (possibly detailed) explanation of how the author applied Fubini's Theorem in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

The set $M=\{(x,y)\in G\times G:\pi(x)^{-1}\pi(xy)=\pi(y)\}$ is co-null by assumption. By Fubini, for almost all $y\in G$, the section $M_y$ of $M$ at level $y$ is (measurable and) co-null. That section is $M_y=\{x\in G:\pi(x)^{-1}\pi(xy)=\pi(y)\}$, so, whenever $M_y$ is co-null. the function $x\mapsto \pi(x)^{-1}\pi(xy)$ is constant a.e. (specifically, constant with value $\pi(y)$ on $M_y$). Since this happens for a.e. $y$, we have that the $H$ in the question is co-null.